# Windows Service stops automatically after a period of time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have this method for the service startup:

```
CheckConfirme.Util.LoggerManager.Logger.WriteInformation("FIPETableService", "Inicializando a nova Thread para a pesquisa.");

var serviceThread = new Thread(ServiceStartMethod);
serviceThread.Start();

CheckConfirme.Util.LoggerManager.Logger.WriteInformation("FIPETableService", "Thread iniciada.");
```

And this for the endup:

```
CheckConfirme.Util.LoggerManager.Logger.WriteInformation("FIPETableService", "Finalizando o Timer.");

if (ServiceThread.IsAlive)
{
    ServiceThread.Abort();
}

CheckConfirme.Util.LoggerManager.Logger.WriteInformation("FIPETableService", "Timer finalizado.");
```

The service starts normally, but after some time of execution, it stop without passing by *ServiceEndup*, this method above, and *OnStop*.

What it can be?

**UPDATE**

As I said, at the comments section, this service stops near, or exactly, 03:00 AM, every day.
This strange event occurred today, at that time, I had to restart the service and it's running up to now, without error or anything like that.

What I'm thinking it could be, it's the Windows Update, or any Windows service, is trying to stop my service and it's throwing this error.

Comment: Perhaps an unhandled exception?

Comment: Or you're simply taking too long to perform an operation.  Read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2009/02/19/in-depth-how-net-managed-services-interact-with-the-servicecontrolmanager-scm-kim-hamilton/ and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/10/managed-windows-services-basics.html, and check the Event Log.  Make sure the code within your service that implements the service is well-behaved.

Comment: Hey @RobertHarvey, I follow the operation by an log and does't take more than 5 ou 6 seconds each operation, so, in theory, it can't be it.

Comment: @ScottHannen, all exceptions are being logged to a TEXT and/or to Event Viewer.

Comment: Well, it has to be something.  Did you read those two articles I linked?  I have a service right now that does exactly what yours does.  I don't know exactly why, but I do know that it's badly-behaving code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I read and could't extract anything from there. :( In a Facebook community, some one suggested that could be Windows Update, because the service stops everytime near, or exactly, 3 AM. Did you know anything about it?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not Windows Update rebooting the whole computer at 3 AM?

Comment: @nvoigt, rebooting I'm sure it's not, but I'm not sure if Windows Update is involved in it.

Comment: What is problem domain (thema, range), Your service is working? Maybe required functionality is stopping at 3:00, breaks open "sessions" etc, for example open socket - event not tested before -> exception?